# Getting the bound Datarow of a Datagrid on postback in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I want to find out the bound datarow or datatable of a datagrid on postback. I have a ButtonColumn in the grid. On click of the button, I'm trying to determine the datarow so that I can access the primary key and pass it to another page. The primary key is not bound and therefore not visible in the row.

For example I have a list of Customers, with an edit button. On clicking of the edit button, I want to open CustomerEdit.aspx?id=10. I am able to trap the click event on the server side in the DataGridCustomer_ItemCommand event. But am not able to get access to the datarow of the e.Item.ItemIndex.

On postback I'm NOT binding the datagrid. On accessing DataGridCustomer.DataSource, I get "Nothing". Is there a way to get the DataSource or the Datarow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The DataBind method your are calling the page load method, when it's not a postback will iterate through your source to build controls.
After that, the source is not kept...only the resulting controls.

I suggest you to build the url to the edit page instead of relying on postback.

In few words, create a `HyperLinkColumn` in your datagrid, and specify the text fields and datafields to build the full url.